# Computing code metrics for emf eol

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf

I would like to measure various code metrics (e.g. McCabe, Halstead) for .eol-scripts (Epsilon Object Language, for querying models).

I've already found and tried [metrics](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) for my modeling project, but it did not compute any metrics for .eol-files in my modeling project.

Eclipse Version is Luna (4.4.2).

Can anyone point me to a tool or into a direction, where I could find a tool that measures code metrics for EOL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly modelling languages are not popular enough to make it into the standard langauges that get support from metric anlaysis tools and it is often the case that you have to develop you own (or an extension if the metrics tool supports extensions e.g. via plugins).
Depending on the complexity of the metrics a simple scripts can be used to measure LOC and number of mappings, for example.
But for more complex metrics you definitley need to first do a static analysis of the EOL script and then compute the metrics.

Regarding the first part, static analysis, the Epsilon framework has recently been enhanced with an EOL static analysis tool! (early versions lacked this support). The tool is available here: [Haetae](https://github.com/epsilonlabs/haetae). With it you can get the static analysis information of your script.

Regarding the second part I am no metrics expert but I guess once the static information is available it should no the hard to calculate them. Sadly a quick overview of the Eclipse metrics project you reference does not provide any information on how to add support for additional languages.